# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException occuring on ArrayList

Tags: java, android

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Options> Options= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Options>();
Options Options = Options.get(selectedFilterIndex);
```

I am getting the error in the above line. The Options is an ArrayList. I tried with `ArrayList` as well as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but get the below error. How handle such exceptions.

> ```
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985): Uncaught exception is: 
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at com.usercontext.CommonActivity$6.doInBackground(AppointmentsActivity5.java:354)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at com.usercontext.CommonActivity$6.doInBackground(AppointmentsActivity5.java:1)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
> 06-21 15:28:23.257: E/XXX(8985):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
> ```

Comment: did you check for selectedFilterIndex <= options.size(). I think selectedFilterIndex is growing and becomes greater than options.size().

Comment: @VaibhavRaj It is not, since `options.size()` is **0**. The list is empty.

Comment: Then, its obvious that you will get this error. Since, your list is of size zero and you are trying to access an index grater than 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be handling this exception - you should be writing code that isn't going to cause it in the first place.

You've just created an empty list - there's *no* value you can pass to `get` which will return a value. The list has a size of 0, and the index is meant to be greater than or equal to 0, and strictly less than the size.

Additionally, your code would be *much* simpler to read if you followed the Java naming conventions of making variables `camelCased` - that will avoid having the same name for both a variable and a type. Also avoid using the same variable name twice...

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Options> allOptions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Options>();
// This will still fail for any value of selectedFilterIndex, as the list
// is empty... but at least it's easier to understand.
Options selectedOptions = allOptions.get(selectedFilterIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just declared the `List` , there are no elements in it yet .

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<Options> Options= new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Options>();
```

And you are trying to `get()` from the `List` with no elements . `ArrayList` internally will use an array buffer to store elements . According to the Javadoc [get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)):

> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())

Hence `Options.get(selectedFilterIndex);` will work only for `(selectedFilterIndex>-1 && selectedFilterIndex < Options.size())`

Comment: You might want to advise following *Java naming conventions*.