# Show error when load more data in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from json and show its in RecyclerView every 10 posts and when user scrolling on RecyclerView show more 10 post and go to end! in this project i use okHTTP v3, Glide and RecyclerView!
**Json link :** [JSON LINK](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1)
I can load first 10 posts, but when scrolling on RecyclerView and show other 10 posts, show me this error :

```
04-27 15:34:33.599 3249-3249/com.tellfa.colony E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.tellfa.colony, PID: 3249
                                                                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 0
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                     at com.tellfa.colony.Activities.Main_page$1$1.run(Main_page.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter2 mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModelsArray;
    private Context context;
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        LoadData();
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdaper = new MainAdapter2(this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);

        mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                dataModels.add(null);
                mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);
                dataModelsArray = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
                        mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());

                        int start = dataModels.size();
                        int end = start + 10;

                        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
                            dataModels.add(new MainDataModel(dataModelsArray.get(i).getId(),
                                    dataModelsArray.get(i).getTitle(),
                                    dataModelsArray.get(i).getContent(),
                                    dataModelsArray.get(i).getThumbnail()));
                            mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size());
                        }
                        mAdaper.setLoaded();

                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask codes:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            JSONObject images=postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair=images.optJSONObject("medium");

                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            String content = postObject.getString("content");
                            String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + thumbnail);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, thumbnail));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for load more data i use Interface class : `OnLoadMoreListener`

**Attention :** Please don't give me negative points, help me and i really need you helps! thanks all <3 How can i fix it?

Comment: Your dataModelsArray size is 0 because you did not added any models in it and start your loop from 0 not size.

Comment: hey hai...tell me this one thing den i will help u, in your code is EventBus mandatory to use or its optional..?

Comment: @SarithaG, no. i use this just for send Data. Do you have other methods?

Comment: @RameshKumar, can you send me true code?

Comment: Where are you sending..If you want i will update full code without using EventBus..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException occuring on ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232856/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-occuring-on-arraylist)

Comment: @SarithaG, yes please update my codes. i just show posts in recyclerView. If you can help me, please help me!

Comment: @F_Feed post your xml files

Comment: @RameshKumarm, main or recycler_raw?

Comment: @SarithaG, can you help me and edit my codes? please

Comment: @F_Feed, check the answer as I understand.. if any query then comment.

Comment: In your server each page has only 10 object..?

Comment: Please see this link (Json Link) : http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts . i edited this for 10 post with this link : http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1

Comment: onEvent() method should when your asyncTask is finished. Then your problem will be solved.

Comment: Your setOnLoadMoreListener() is completely wrong. There only u r getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. Just comment for loop then you wont get any exception bt the next 10 posts wont be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                dataModels.add(null);
                mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);
                dataModelsArray = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
                        mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());

                        int start = dataModels.size();
                        int end = start + 10;

                        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
                            dataModels.add(new MainDataModel(dataModelsArray.get(i).getId(),
                                    dataModelsArray.get(i).getTitle(),
                                    dataModelsArray.get(i).getContent(),
                                    dataModelsArray.get(i).getThumbnail()));
                            mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size());
                        }
                        mAdaper.setLoaded();

                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

to

```
  mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                dataModels.add(null);
                mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);
              LoadData(pageNumber);
            }
        });
```

and change this method:

```
@Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

to:
int pageNumber = 1;
         @Subscribe
            public void onEvent(List mainInfoModels) {

```
    if(dataModels.size()>0){
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            mAdaper.setLoaded();
            }

mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
pageNumber++;

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

It is just overview as I understand: you are not doing anything with the dataModelsArray. 
Check this out hope this helps. As you did not provided all the code

EDIT: 
for your Second answer you are saying 10 post are repeatedly showing because you are not passing the page number:

Change this method:

```
 public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }
```

to:

```
 public void getMainDataInfo(Context context, int pageNumber) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page="+pageNumber);
    }
```

change this method to:

```
private void LoadData() {
        MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
    }
```

to

```
 private void LoadData(int pageNumber) {
        MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this, pageNumber);
    }
```

> Change LoadData() to LoadData(pageNumber)

make an integer in your activity class, increment it when you get response and pass incremented pageNumber to this method.

Thank hope it solve you issue. Accept it as answer as others can get idea.

Comment: Thank you. but when edit my code in logcat show this error : `04-27 16:43:29.076 21106-21106/com.tellfa.colony E/EventBus: Could not dispatch event: class java.util.ArrayList to subscribing class class com.tellfa.colony.Activities.Main_page
                                                             java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1` for this line : `dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);` and not show to any post. Even not show first 10 post!

Comment: Hey Ramesh thanks you, this problem is ok ! but i have strange bug :( when scrolling on RecyclerView not load next 10 post! just load first 10 post and show this below posts! (just load first 10 post!) please edit post to load next 10 posts. Thanks

Comment: @F_Feed I have edited the question. if helps then accept it

Comment: Thank you @Ramesh. this is finally my question, please answer to me. (because i am amateur:( ). when change code with **pageNumber**, in `LoadData` need to me page number! but i don't know how to added this and set counter for **pageNumber** in `MainActivity` ! please add this, please my dear friend >3

Comment: In setOnLoadMoreListener() he's created new Object for dataModelsArray. So that Object has no data. There he is getting IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: @SarithaG, he has nothing to do this datamodelsArray, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code :

And Delete Don't use your MainDataInfo class. I have implemented that in Main_Page.java itself.

Your Main_Page.java:

```
  public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity  {

private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private RelativeLayout root;
private ImageView menu_image;
private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
private MainAdapter2 mAdaper;
private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
protected Handler handler;
private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private int pageCount = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
    handler = new Handler();
    loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    }
    LoadData(pageCount);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Main_page.this);
    // Menu
    root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
    View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(Main_page.this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
    root.addView(guillotineMenu);
    menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
    new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
            .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
            .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
            .setClosedOnStart(true)
            .build();
    // RecyclerView and setData
    main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
    main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            dataModels.add(null);
            mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
                    mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());

                    LoadData(++pageCount);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
  /*
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
    mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);

    if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
        main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}*/

private void LoadData(int pageNumber) {
    new APIInfoAsyncTask().execute(ServerAddress + "page=" + pageNumber);
}


private class APIInfoAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<MainDataModel>> {
    private String ou_response;



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(Main_page.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<MainDataModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        List<MainDataModel> responseData = new ArrayList<>();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                .build();

        Response response;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            ou_response = response.body().string();
            response.body().close();
            if (ou_response != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                    JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                    infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                        JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                        JSONObject images = postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                        JSONObject imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("medium");

                        int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                        String title = postObject.getString("title");
                        String content = postObject.getString("content");
                        String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                        Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                        Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                        Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + thumbnail);

                        //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                        responseData.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, thumbnail));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MainDataModel> result) {
        CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
        dataModels.addAll(result);


            mAdaper = new MainAdapter2(Main_page.this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
            main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);

    }
}
}
```

Use your adapter class without any edit,And dont use EventBus.

Comment: thanks, but show error for `implements AsyncResponse` and say to me i should create **interface** class with this name! how can edit this?

Comment: Sry i forgt to remove it. you just remove that implmentation.

Comment: When added this codes, not show me any posts! Even not show first 10 posts!

Comment: Are you here @Saritha G ?

Comment: hey @Saritha G go to sleep? :D

Comment: If you online in stack, please answer to me <3

Comment: you just remove the if else conditions..set only adapter in onPostExecute() method. looks @ my updated answer in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: When update codes with your last update, show me just last post! (1 post) . can you send me skype/telegram/ or other messanger ID?

Comment: I updated my answer..This is my edit. Use if it wont work, i will  give you my id.

Comment: Update again my codes with your last code, but just show 1 last post! :( please give me your ID.

Comment: What do u mean by last post..is it giving correct response. You can continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110467/discussion-between-f-feed-and-saritha-g).

Comment: Please Come chat screen